# Google optimize A/B testing weightage not working properly

Tags: ab-testing, google-optimize

I am using **Google optimize A/B testing** on my website, I've kept 3 different variants for the same, I am dividing all the weightage among these new variants & giving *0 weightage* to my ***original*** variant, still, sometimes I'm getting the original page.

Does anyone have any idea why is this happening?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It could be due the **target rules**

An example would be if your page is visible as both `www.example.io/original.html` and example.io/original.html

Also, you need to take about the session if you are managing any,

> If you change the weights after the experiment starts (i.e. you set
> the **Variant 1** to **100%**) then all the returning visitors that
> were assigned to another variant or the original will remain there and
> see that.

Read more at. : https://support.google.com/optimize/thread/7450936/in-weighting-does-100-really-mean-100?hl=en